# Travel/Travelers & Journey/Journeyers

Tags: suffixes, morphology

When I change Travel to Travelers, what is that? Is that some sort of participle? Also, how is this accomplished with Exodus? As in 'Exodus-ers'. Does one use the Latin ablative?

Comment: What's the ablative (in English)? Also, the premiss seems to be flawed, since *Exodus* isn't a verb.

Comment: Latin ablative. And Journey is certainly a noun.

Comment: By comparison with *traveler* (BrE *traveller*), [we don't normally](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=travellers%2Ctravelers%2Cjourneyers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) use *journeyer* anyway. But at least it's "credible", because *journey* can be used as a verb. *Exodus* is only valid as a noun, from which you can't reasonably derive another type of noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not regarded as *inflection* but *derivation*, i.e. *traveler* (gosh it's hard for me to type the American spelling) is regarded as a different word from *travel*, where *traveling* is not.

So *traveler* is not regarded as the "anything" of *travel*, but as an *agentive* derived from *travel*.

This distinction is to some degree arbitrary, but very well established.

Comment: It seems as though there is still 'verb-ness' in the word Traveler. It has a verb essence.

Comment: Yes. But it is regarded as a derived noun, in the way that _traveling_ is not. As I said, this is to some degree arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know how this is accomplished in Latin?

Comment: More on derivation vs. inflection here: http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOflinguisticTerms/ComparisonOfInflectionAndDeriv.htm

Comment: In Latin, there was an agentive suffix _-tor_. I don't know how productive it was.

Comment: It’s hard for me to type that spelling, too, and I am American. We don’t all kowtow to Microsoft Word, but I do get tired of explaining to people I’m neither wrong nor foreign to spell it *traveller*.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no grammatical form called the "ablative" in English.

The suffix *-er* is sometimes called an *agentive* suffix. This may be occasionally misleading, since it does not necessarily indicate agents, but that's the best term that I'm aware of. Most English speakers wouldn't call it an agentive suffix, though, they'd just call it "a suffix" or "the -er ending".

It only attaches to verbs, so *travel -> traveler* and *journey -> journeyer* are fine, but *exodus -> !exoduser* is not allowed, since *exodus* is not a verb.

Comment: Edited for clarity. How do you accomplish the agentive suffix in Latin?

Comment: In Latin the ending is usually _-tor_, but I don't know how freely it was used to make new words. We have plenty of English words that use that ending, but as you say we also have agent nouns in _-er_.

Comment: Noted. Thank you. Would +1 if I could.

Comment: @KJO: There is currently no Latin.SE, but there is a proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48247/latin-language-usage

Comment: Have you checked in OED that 'exodus' doesn't occur as a verb? I've seen it used as one, in print. _Though productivity is gradable in English, and I'd consider 'exoduser' unacceptable._

Answer (score 0):

Exodus is not native Latin, but a Greek borrowing.

Two likely Latin verbs to use instead are

> exeo, exire, exivi(ii), exitus - come/go/sail/march/move out/forth/away, leave

and

> fugio, fugere, fugi, fugitus - flee, fly, run away; go into exile

Apparently the following Latin derivatives exist

> profugio, profugere, profugi, - (verb) - escape, escape from; run away from
>
> profugus, profugi (noun) - exile; fugitive; refugee; runaway

A nice Latin-English bilingual dictionary can be explored here:
http://www.latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/profugus

Comment: Thank you for addressing the second part of my question. +1 For what it's worth.